# How to save nested list with sqflite in flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, sqflite

> Here I want to add `bookmark` functionality in my `flutter` news application. I `get` data from `APIs`. I display that data below.

[This Image shows you how I get data from APIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rAPg.png)

> I am using this snippet for saving data with `SQflite` which I display below. I save this file with name `bookmark_db_provider.dart`.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'home_screen_data.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DBProvider {
  static Database _database;
  static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();

  DBProvider._();

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) _database = await initDB();

    return _database;
  }

  initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'ProductData.db');

    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {},
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute('CREATE TABLE ProductData('
          'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,' //id
          'categoryName Text,' //headline
          'publisherName Text,'  //description
          'isAvailable Text,'      //content
          'categoryImgUrl Text'  //image
          ')');
    });
  }

  createProductData(ProductData productData) async {
    await deleteAllProductData();
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db.insert('ProductData', productData.toJson());

    return res;
  }

  Future<int> deleteAllProductData() async {
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db.delete('DELETE FROM ProductData');

    return res;
  }

  Future<List<ProductData>> getProductDataList() async {
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ProductData");

    List<ProductData> list = res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((x) => ProductData.fromJson(x)).toList() : [];

    return list;
  }
}
```

So, I want to how to `save data` and `get data` this with `SQflite database` in `flutter`. How I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question and hopes you have gotten an answer to it. However, a lot of flutter dev using sqflite struggles with handling data in a nested array format of the type mentioned e.g

````
``` {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "xyz",
  "images": [
    {
      "imageId": 1,
      "image": "image1"
    },
    {
      "imageId": 2,
      "image": "image2"
    }
  ]
} 
```
````

Since json handling is not part of sqflite at the moment, it is suggested to either;
a., save inner array as a string/text field in the 'image' column of table 'data' like
**

> "[{"imageId": 1, "image": 'image1'}, {"imageId": 2, "image":
> 'image2'},}"

**  , no guaranty.

or, b., flatten out the inner array so as to have only **

> data[id, name, image1, image2, image3,...].

** this approach may be possible in a simple array as given but in a complex system. flattening out may be really cumbersome.

my suggestion, create two tables, one for data, and another for images. let each row of images table have reference or relationship with corresponding data table row.  Your data class and images class will be something like,

````
```
class Data {
    int dataId;
    String name;
    List<Image> images;
    data({this.id, this.images, this.name});
    ...
```
````

and

````
``` 
class Image {    
    int imageId;
    int dataId;
    String image;
    Image({this.imageId, this.dataId, this.image});
    ...
    } 
```
````

Your sqflite table data will have only two fields 'dataId' and 'name' and the image table must include 'dataId' as the relationship between the two tables.

to save data, you can use transactions like

````
```
void saveData(Data data, Map<String, Object> map) async {
    await db.execute(""" INSERT INTO "data" (name) values (?) """, [data.name]);

// retrieve dataId of the new row inserted. last_inserted_rowid can also be used if the database does not contain several tables that may have been updated or saved before completing the transaction.
 
 int dataId;
    List<Map> x = await db.query('data', columns: ['dataId'], where: 'name = ?', whereArgs: [data.name]);
    dataId = x[x.length - 1]['dataId'];
   

    db.transaction((txn) async {
      var batch = txn.batch();
      data.images
          .map((e) => {
                batch.rawInsert(
                    """ INSERT INTO "images" (dataId,image,) values (?,?,?,? ) """, [dataId, e.image])
              }).toList();
    });
  }
 ```
````

to retrieve data and images, you can try something like

````
 ```
 Data _data = new Data();
 
 Future<void> fetchData() async {
    if (db != null) {
      // do not execute if db is not instantiate
      //retrieve all data from data table and store in instantiated, also instantiate images array as empty list
      final dataList = await db.query(data);
      _data = (dataList as List)
          .map(
            (data) => Data(
              dataId: data['dataId'],
              name: data['name'],
             images: data['images'] != null ? data['images'] : []
            )) .toList();
    
      _data.forEach((data)  async {if (data.images != null) {
        List<Image> _images = [];
        var imageResults = await db.query(images,where: 'dataId =?', whereArgs: [data.dataId]);
      
        _images = (imageResults as List).map((e) => Image(
          imageId: e['imageId'],
          dataId: e['dataId'],
          image: e['image']
        )).toList();
        _data.images.addAll(_images);       
      }  });

    }
  }
  ```
````

with that approach, you should be able to handle nested array in flutter and sqflite

Answer (score -1):

I might be unclear with your question, but according to what I understood,

You need to call the method of this provider with data that you want:

```
DBProvider.init() // Use this only one which when the application is instaled
```

After that, you can call these methods from anywhere to put and get data

```
DBProvider.createProductData(productData) //insert data
```

Get data

```
DBProvider.getProductDataList() //get data
```

Comment: Above display code I use for list item as `[{id,name,},{id,name},{id, name},...]`, but I want to save data list as `[data:{id, name,image[image1, image2]},{id, name,image[image1, image2]},{id, name,image[image1, image2]},...]`. So, how can I do this?  @Anirudh Bagri

Comment: is there any reason you want to store it like that? 
Once you retrieve data from DB, you can put the list in another data structure.

Comment: There is not specific reason for data store, but I get data from this format from my WorkPlace. That is why I use this type of data. @Anirudh Bagri.

Comment: If that is the case, you can store each item of the array as a row in SQLite.

Comment: share any reference link for this type of code because I am new to flutter so please share this reference link for this. @Anirush Bagri

Comment: I don't have any code handy, try looping through the result and insert them one by one using DBProvider.createProductData(productData)